# Trying to get a db backup from different pc on LAN network generates empty sql file

Tags: java, mysql, database-backups

When I try to get a database backup from a different PC (called pac 1), which is connected to same local network with the accessing computer (called pac 2) server to a local machine using mysqldump

Database is on PC 1 and I want to generate a database backup on PC by executing java program. Currently I achieved this, but there is an error so an empty SQL file is created.

- `userPathForDbBackup` is a string which takes the path from user through filechooser
- `mySqlPath` is a variable which is a file path on pc2

```
String mySqlPath="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqldump.exe";
String name="name";
String pathFinal=userPathForDbBackup + "\\Backup_" + name + ".sql";
String[] command = {mySqlPath,"mysqldump", "-h"+dbh, "-u "+dbUser, "-p" + dbPass, dbName,">"+pathFinal};
try{
  connection = create_connection.jdbc.getCon();
  String executeCmd = "";
  if(connection!=null){
    executeCmd = "mysqldump -h"+dbh+"-u"+dbUser+" -p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+"file.sql" ;
    System.out.println();
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    Process runtimeProcess =pb.start();
    // Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    if(processComplete == 0){
      System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
    }
  } else{
    System.out.println("connection not sucess");
  }
}catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This doesn't throw any exception, but it creates an empty SQL file in the user selected directory.

Comment: "there is an error", for all we know, that is the DB the code finds

Comment: @Stultuske sorry i didnt get you..

Comment: for all we know, the code works perfectly, but it just doesn't find any/the database

Comment: @Stultuske but the program exit code is -1.. do you have any suggestion for a fix..thank you

Comment: have you debugged your code? even formatting it here won't work, so I am not going to make further assumptions about the code you are not showing, or about the details of this code

Comment: @Stultuske i tried using the debug point..but it does not go to inside of constructors or method bodies...in this peace of codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String dbName = "";
            String dbUser = "";
            String dbPass = "";
            String dbh = "";
            String dbport = "";
            Connection connection;


//userPathForDbBackup is user selected path from file chooser


            String pathFinal=userPathForDbBackup + "\\Backup_" + name + ".sql";
            System.out.println(userPathForDbBackup+"before");
            userPathForDbBackup= userPathForDbBackup+"\\Backup_name.sql";
            System.out.println(userPathForDbBackup+"after");

            String folderPath = userPathForDbBackup.substring(0, userPathForDbBackup.lastIndexOf("\\")) ;


            File path =new File(userPathForDbBackup);

            String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin/mysqldump.exe", "--user=" + dbUser, "--password=" + dbPass,""+ dbName,"-r"+path};

            try{

                connection = create_connection.jdbc.getCon();

                if(connection!=null){
                    Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
                    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
                    if (processComplete != 0) { //4
                        // something went wrong
                        InputStream errorStream = runtimeProcess.getErrorStream();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[errorStream.available()];
                        errorStream.read(buffer);

                        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
                    }
                } else{
                    System.out.println("connection not sucess");
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

finaly got this code to work